# How long can flour dough sit on counter?

Tags: baking, food-safety

I'm making flour tortillas with all purpose flour, butter, water, and baking powder. How long can the dough sit on counter?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 accounts, you should ask a mod to join them https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your recipe is safe at room temperature.  If you are talking about hours (even 24 hours), there is no safety issue.  If you are talking about a longer period of time (days?), your likely risks would be mold growth, or rancidity.